# GMOD LUA: Restricting wire support to job

Tags: lua, garrys-mod

If you're reading this right now, I expect you to know something about how lua and Gmod works together. I'm recoding a fading door addon with wire support, on a DarkRP Gmod server. I'm having problems with restricting the wire support to a specific DarkRP job. To make it easy on myself, i started off with trying to restrict it to the TEAM_GANG job. This is the bit of code I changed.

```
local function customCheck(pl)
    return table.HasValue({TEAM_GANG}, pl:Team())
end

local function dooEet(pl, Ent, stuff)
    if Ent.isFadingDoor then
        if Ent.fadeDeactivate then Ent:fadeDeactivate() end
        RemoveKeys(Ent)
    else
        Ent.isFadingDoor = true
        Ent.fadeActivate = fadeActivate
        Ent.fadeDeactivate = fadeDeactivate
        Ent.fadeToggleActive = fadeToggleActive
        Ent:CallOnRemove("Fading Doors", RemoveKeys)
        if WireLib and customCheck(pl) then
            doWireInputs(Ent)
            doWireOutputs(Ent)
            Ent.fadeTriggerInput = Ent.fadeTriggerInput or Ent.TriggerInput
            Ent.TriggerInput = TriggerInput
            if !Ent.IsWire then
                if !Ent.fadePreEntityCopy and Ent.PreEntityCopy then Ent.fadePreEntityCopy = Ent.PreEntityCopy end
                Ent.PreEntityCopy = PreEntityCopy
                if !Ent.fadePostEntityPaste and Ent.PreEntityCopy then Ent.fadePostEntityPaste = Ent.PostEntityPaste end
                Ent.PostEntityPaste = PostEntityPaste
            end
        end
    end
    Ent.fadeUpNum = numpad.OnUp(pl, stuff.key, "Fading Door onUp", Ent)
    Ent.fadeDownNum = numpad.OnDown(pl, stuff.key, "Fading Door onDown", Ent)
    Ent.fadeToggle = stuff.toggle
    Ent.fadeReversed = stuff.reversed
    Ent.fadeKey = stuff.key
    Ent.fadeCanDisableMotion = stuff.CanDisableMotion
    Ent.fadeDoorMaterial = stuff.DoorMaterial
    Ent.fadeDoorOpenSound = stuff.DoorOpenSound
    Ent.fadeDoorLoopSound = stuff.DoorLoopSound
    Ent.fadeDoorCloseSound = stuff.DoorCloseSound
    if stuff.reversed then Ent:fadeActivate() end
    duplicator.StoreEntityModifier(Ent, "Fading Door", stuff)
    return true
end
```

I only added the customCheck function

```
local function customCheck(pl)
    return table.HasValue({TEAM_GANG}, pl:Team())
end
```

And checked for the team here

```
if WireLib and customCheck(pl) then
```

This removed access from all jobs and didn't give access to the TEAM_GANG job either. I do not see why this is not working and I can't find another way to do this, so I am kinda stuck.

If you want the whole code, I have it pasted into a pastebin. Link: https://pastebin.com/UrkyK8e2

Answer (score 0):

---------------------------------------------------------UPDATE---------------------------------------------------------

I found another way of doing it, and it worked.

The code now looks like this.

```
local function dooEet(pl, Ent, stuff)
    if Ent.isFadingDoor then
        if Ent.fadeDeactivate then Ent:fadeDeactivate() end
        RemoveKeys(Ent)
    else
        Ent.isFadingDoor = true
        Ent.fadeActivate = fadeActivate
        Ent.fadeDeactivate = fadeDeactivate
        Ent.fadeToggleActive = fadeToggleActive
        Ent:CallOnRemove("Fading Doors", RemoveKeys)
        if WireLib then
            if (team.GetName(pl:Team()) == "Gangster") then
                doWireInputs(Ent)
                doWireOutputs(Ent)
                Ent.fadeTriggerInput = Ent.fadeTriggerInput or Ent.TriggerInput
                Ent.TriggerInput = TriggerInput
                if !Ent.IsWire then
                    if !Ent.fadePreEntityCopy and Ent.PreEntityCopy then Ent.fadePreEntityCopy = Ent.PreEntityCopy end
                    Ent.PreEntityCopy = PreEntityCopy
                    if !Ent.fadePostEntityPaste and Ent.PreEntityCopy then Ent.fadePostEntityPaste = Ent.PostEntityPaste end
                    Ent.PostEntityPaste = PostEntityPaste
                end
            end
        end
    end
    Ent.fadeUpNum = numpad.OnUp(pl, stuff.key, "Fading Door onUp", Ent)
    Ent.fadeDownNum = numpad.OnDown(pl, stuff.key, "Fading Door onDown", Ent)
    Ent.fadeToggle = stuff.toggle
    Ent.fadeReversed = stuff.reversed
    Ent.fadeKey = stuff.key
    Ent.fadeCanDisableMotion = stuff.CanDisableMotion
    Ent.fadeDoorMaterial = stuff.DoorMaterial
    Ent.fadeDoorOpenSound = stuff.DoorOpenSound
    Ent.fadeDoorLoopSound = stuff.DoorLoopSound
    Ent.fadeDoorCloseSound = stuff.DoorCloseSound
    if stuff.reversed then Ent:fadeActivate() end
    duplicator.StoreEntityModifier(Ent, "Fading Door", stuff)
    return true
end
```